# How to count total number of quote in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My question is: using XSLT, how to count the total number of QUOTE tag (please see the sample code below)
The result need to be exported in HTLM, it will display like this: There are total 6 quotes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="text.xsl" ?>

    <quotes>
      <quote>Quote 1 </quote>
      <quote>Quote 2</quote>
      <quote>Quote 3</quote>
      <quote>Quote 4</quote>
      <quote>Quote 5</quote>
      <quote>Quote 6</quote>
    </quotes>
```

I already try this XSLT code but it does not work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
      version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(//quote)"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would you please help me through this problem? Thank you

Comment: Hint: probably you don't know that you can accept the best answer -- by clicking the OK/Accept mark that is displayed next to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

**Your XPath expression**, though not very efficient, **produces the right result**.

When the transformation is run with Saxon 9.1.0.5J, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>6
```

**The problem seems to be that this is an XSLT 2.0 transformation** (which it doesn't need to be!), and you seem to be trying to run it within a browser. **Unfortunately, today's browsers do not support (yet) XSLT 2.0**.

***The solution is to simply change the version to `1.0`.***

You also don't need the XML Schema namespace for this transformation.

Finally, if the structure of the provided XML document is not going to change, a more efficient XPath expression (because using the `//` abbreviation causes the whole (sub)tree starting at the top element node to be scanned), will be the following:

```
count(/*/quote)
```

**Putting all these together we get the following transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 >
 <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/quote)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and it produces the wanted result**.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work fine in Firefox 3, and IE6. more information about your setup?